# Logging user out of Auth0 from server side code

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, auth0

I'm trying to create a **custom** mfa solution for my site, which uses Auth0.

My site uses a react front end, asp.net core backend, and auth0.com for its authentication.

The flow I am trying to create, is for the user to click "login" on the react front end site, it then redirects them to Auth0, they login, which redirects them back. 
From the page it is redirected to, it makes a initial AXIOS call to my asp.net core server. On the server I check to see if its a recognised ip address, if its not, I would like the server to send a message to Auth0 to end he session, and then I redirect the user to a splash page saying "check email for url".

The problem is, the only way I can find to log a user out, is to redirect the user to a log out URL. which would need to be done in javascript, and could be hijacked.

Comment: Perhaps just [prevent them logging in from invalid IPs](https://community.auth0.com/t/ability-to-restrict-user-access-by-a-specific-ip-address/31133/6) instead?

Comment: Uhm... why not simply testing the IP **BEFORE** you redirect them to Auth0???

Comment: because im checking if THAT USER has logged in before with the IP address. I'm creating a custom login guard so that if its a new ip for that user, it sends them an authorization request to their email.